# Microsoft Word VBA macro to read comments

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'm trying to read comments for figures in a document using the code below

```
For Each iShp In .InlineShapes
  iShp.Select

  If Selection.Comments.Count > 0 Then
    MsgBox Selection.Comments(1).Range.text
  End If
Next
```

The shapes are selected properly, however the count is always 0...

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't believe ```InlineShapes``` has a comments property. What you have there is taking the comments from the ```selection```, of which there are not any. There is ```.AlternativeText``` and ```.Title``` for shapes.

Comment: You need to provide more information about these comments. It's not clear where they're located. Perhaps a screen shot could help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternative way to read all the comments:

```
Option Explicit

Sub DisplayCommentText()
    With ActiveDocument
        Dim cmt As Comment
        For Each cmt In .Comments
            Debug.Print cmt.Range.Text
        Next cmt
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is very similar to what I ended up doing!